# How can I instruct sqlx about this custom type I'm using for OffsetDateTime?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I have a custom time type because [time's authors doesn't want to add a Default value yet](https://github.com/time-rs/time/issues/370):

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct OffsetDateTime(pub time::OffsetDateTime);

impl OffsetDateTime {
    pub fn now_utc() -> Self {
        Self(time::OffsetDateTime::now_utc())
    }
}

impl Default for OffsetDateTime {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self(time::OffsetDateTime::UNIX_EPOCH)
    }
}

impl From<time::OffsetDateTime> for OffsetDateTime {
    fn from(o: time::OffsetDateTime) -> Self {
        Self(o)
    }
}

impl From<OffsetDateTime> for time::OffsetDateTime {
    fn from(o: OffsetDateTime) -> Self {
        o.0
    }
}
```

If I use this simple sqlx code:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default, sqlx::FromRow)]
pub struct Player {
    pub id: String,
    pub created_at: OffsetDateTime,
    pub name: String,
}

let pla = sqlx::query_as!(
    Player,
    r#"SELECT * from player where id = $1"#,
    '1'
)
.fetch_one(&*self.pool)
.await?;
```

it errors with:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   |
66 |           let pla = sqlx::query_as!(
   |  ___________________^
67 | |             Player,
68 | |             r#"SELECT * from player where id = $1"#,
70 | |             id
71 | |         )
   | |_________^ expected struct `custom::types::OffsetDateTime`, found struct `time::OffsetDateTime`
   |
   = note: struct `time::OffsetDateTime` and struct `custom::types::OffsetDateTime` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: struct `time::OffsetDateTime` is defined in crate `time`
  --> C:\Users\Fred\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\time-0.3.17\src\offset_date_time.rs:31:1
   |
31 | pub struct OffsetDateTime {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: struct `custom::types::OffsetDateTime` is defined in crate `custom`
   |
4  | pub struct OffsetDateTime(pub time::OffsetDateTime);
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::sqlx_macros::expand_query` which comes from the expansion of the macro `sqlx::query_as` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: try wrapping the expression in `custom::types::OffsetDateTime`
  --> C:\Users\Fred\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\sqlx-0.6.2\src\macros\mod.rs:561:9
   |
561|         custom::types::OffsetDateTime($crate::sqlx_macros::expand_query!(record = $out_struct, source = $query, args = [$($args)*]))
   |         ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++                                                                                             +
```

How can I fix this?

Should I instruct sqlx to handle my custom `OffsetDateTime`? How?

Comment: @tadman, can you help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs on [`query_as`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/macro.query_as.html):

> The field types must be the Rust equivalent of their SQL counterparts

Means you have to use the types in the type map corresponding to your db ([example for postgres](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/postgres/types/index.html)).

Or in other words, you can't use custom types with `query_as`

Comment: But it's the same type, only wrapped. I think should be there a way to do this...

Comment: "only wrapped" means they are as different as apples and oranges, you can't compare them.

Comment: So I give   up? There is no other way?

Comment: Well no, you just can't use `query_as` with a custom type a `query` will work with them, and so will `query_as` with the standard types.